# What does Entity Framework Context Add do?

Tags: entity-framework, addition, dbset

we are using Entity Framework 5.0 and have a use case for creating a preview.
So I though I'd see if I could use EF to build my preview in EF data model classes and *not* persist (no SaveChanges).
(I could of course do this without EF, but I'd thought I'd experiment.)

Now I see some strange things when adding to my context.

- In the code snippet below, the Add calls do not effect the collections added to (the DbSets). before = after = 0.
- When I do Child.Add, the relation between parent and child is set (parent.Child now contains child). It did not do that before calling Add.

  ```
   private void Insert(Parent parent, Child child)
   {
       // Context.Parent does not get any items:
       int before = this.Context.Parent.Count();
       this.Context.Parent.Add(parent);
       int after = this.Context.Parent.Count();

       // This affects Parent.Child:
       this.Context.Child.Add(child);
   }
  ```

Here is the vital part from the Context class (removed a lot for clarity):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>(entity =>
        {
            // Removed code here...

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
                .WithMany(p => p.Child)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ChildId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Child_Parent");
        });
```

So what does Add really do?

Comment: That's relationship fixup. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#relationship-fixup

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer!
So Adding causes relationship fixup.
But why does not Add add anything to the DbSet? Or is it added to some hidden collection, until SaveChanges?

Comment: A `DbSet` doesn't *contain* anything, it's nothing but a query waiting to be executed. It's all about entities in EF's change tracker, i.e. attached entities.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase the question:
Why is this.Context.Parent.Count() = 0 after "this.Context.Parent.Add(parent)"?